# C# move file with 2 mapped drives

Tags: c#, mapped-drive, file-move

I need to move a file existing on a mapped folder named `A:\` to another mapped folder `B:\` using the code below

```
File.Move(@"A:\file.txt",@"B:\");
```

it return the error below

```
Could not find file 'A:\file.txt'.
```

i tried to open A:\file.txt in folder explorer and it open the file normally

Comment: according to MSDN you need to specify the destination filename, not only path.

Comment: [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx). `public static void Move(
 string sourceFileName,
 string destFileName
)`

Comment: What does `File.Exist(@"A:\file.txt")` give you

Comment: With no other information this will be a no repro.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `File.Move` only works for files on local drives.

[`File.Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx) actually invokes [`MoveFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx) which states that both *source* and *destination* should be:

> The current name of the file or directory on the **local** computer.

You would be better by using a combination of [`File.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`File.Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx).

Copy the file from `A` to `B`, then delete the file from `A`.

Comment: From Msdn : "Remarks: This method works across disk volumes"

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, [`File.Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx) needs sourceFileName and destFileName.
And you are missing the Filename in the second parameter.

If you want to move you file and keep the same name you can Extract the File name from the sourceFileName with [`GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) and use it in your destFileName

```
string sourceFileName = @"V:\Nothing.txt";
string destPath   = @"T:\";
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFileName);

File.Move(sourceFileName, destPath + fileName );
```

Here is a debug code:

```
public static void Main() 
{
    string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
    string path2 = @"c:\temp2\MyTest.txt";
    try 
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            // This statement ensures that the file is created,
            // but the handle is not kept.
            Console.WriteLine("The original file does not exists, let's Create it.");
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) {}
        }

        // Ensure that the target does not exist.
        if (File.Exists(path2)) {           
            Console.WriteLine("The target file already exists, let's Delete it.");
            File.Delete(path2);
        }

        // Move the file.
        File.Move(path, path2);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} was moved to {1}.", path, path2);

        // See if the original exists now.
        if (File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The original file still exists, which is unexpected.");
        } 
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The original file no longer exists, which is expected.");
        }   

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue: Could not find file 'A:\file.txt

Comment: Please use the msdn code exemple. An tell us Whats your issue

Comment: no one of the 2 codes below works: `File.Move(@"A:\\file.txt", @"B:\\" + Path.GetFileName("A:\\file.txt"));` and this `File.Move("A:\\file.txt", "B:\\" + Path.GetFileName("A:\\file.txt"));`

Comment: same issue : couldnt file `Could not find file 'A:\\file.txt`

Comment: May you please follow those simple step: 1/; click on any MSDN link for `File.Move` 2/. Go to the code exemple 3/. Copy past it into your code. Using an sample empty txt file (not your real file please)  4/. Tell us where it fail...

Comment: PS: "You cannot use the Move method to overwrite an existing file."

Comment: Could not find a part of the path 'A:\file.txt'

Comment: May I have the error dump? it it a IOException, argument null , NotSupportedException? Because it's look like a IOException but the Msdn code has a `File.Exists(path)`. So it can't be

Comment: I have add a debug code that is 99% copy past from MSDN exemple may you run it and past the console result please. don't forget the break point. And use a test file.